# MultiBinding StringFormat Logic: Don't Print Delimiter

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, multibinding, string-formatting

Given this XAML ...

```
<TextBlock Name="First">Fred</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Name="Last">Flintstone</TextBlock>
<TextBlock >
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{1}, {0}">
            <Binding ElementName="First" Path="Text"/>
            <Binding ElementName="Last" Path="Text"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

How would I not print the ', ' delimiter if first **or** last name isNullOrEmpty?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use a `Converter` that uses `String.Join` which results in this behavior automatically if you remove null entries from the array.